# SQL Overwrite value in column in group by

Tags: sql, aggregation

lets say i have following sql-table

```
fruit | amount | date
-------------------------
apple |    2   | 2019
apple |    3   | 2018
apple |    2   | 
peach |    2   | 
peach |    3   | 2017
```

where i want to fill up the null values in the column date with the earliest date of each fruit, so that the date column consists no null values. The result should look like this:

```
fruit | amount | date
-------------------------
apple |    2   | 2019
apple |    3   | 2018
apple |    2   | 2018
peach |    2   | 2017
peach |    3   | 2017
```

Any ideas how to do this in sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method to do this sans analytic functions uses a correlated subquery:

```sql
SELECT
    fruit,
    amount,
    COALESCE(date, (SELECT MIN(date) FROM yourTable t2 WHERE t2.fruit = t1.fruit)) date
FROM yourTable t1;
```

We could also use an aggregation join approach:

```sql
SELECT
    t1.fruit,
    t1.amount,
    COALESCE(t1.date, t2.min_date) AS date
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT fruit, MIN(date) AS min_date
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY fruit
) t2
    ON t2.fruit = t1.fruit;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(date, min(date) over (partition by fruit)) as imputed_date
from t;
```